# How to force my wifi users to "accept" my TOS?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, ssid

In some public wifi places I see landing pages forcing me to accept their TOS and also enter a password before I can browse the internet using their wifi connectiion. I was wondering how can I do this to my own wifi connection?

Comment: Not all routers support it, but you could start with looking at something like [wifidog](http://dev.wifidog.org/).  I think that DD-WRT supports it too, so you probably need a router supported by DD-WRT to consider this.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a router compatible with one of the open source router firmware packages, there is free and/or open source Wifi hotspot firmware available as well. [How To Set Up Your Own Free Wifi Hotspot With DD-WRT](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/set-free-wifi-hotspot-ddwrt/) describes the process using one well known router / FOSS firmware combination.

Answer (score -2):

Its called a captive portal and yes, you can shove any ridiculous TOS you want down the throats of helpless road warriors.

Your router may or may not support this

Comment: I'm pretty sure those terms, legally, are entirely unenforceable for what it's worth.

Comment: @Ramhound - You're quite naive.

Comment: @Ramhound, At a guess, they display them exactly because people wrongly think they are actually enforceable. The same reason people have email signatures of "you *must* destroy this email if it is not intended for you"... oh yeah, says who?!

Comment: @Ramhound then someone didn't bother to appeal when they should have. http://www.economist.com/node/18529895